# Display a negative value in on cell

Tags: excel

I have a column of plus values that keeps a running total however I would like to display this sum of these in the “negative” in one separate cell or block.

Answer (score 0):

sum of positive values in column A,

```
=sumifs(a:a, a:a, ">"&0)
```

sum of negative values in column A,

```
=sumifs(a:a, a:a, "<"&0)
```

these 'sums' should not be in column a or you will get a circular reference. if they have to be in column a, cut the full column references down to the actual data range.